# Difference between dataframe's $ and [] functions

Tags: r, dataframe

How & Why, are a dataframe's $ and [] functions different when assigning values.
Can I tweak the `abc.df[,"b"] = get("b")` line to have same effect as `abc.df$b = get("b")`

```
abc.df = NULL
a = 1:10
abc.df = data.frame(a)
b_vector = 11:20
b_list = rep(list(c(1,2)),10)

sp_colmns1 = c("b_vector")
# This works :
abc.df$b_vector_method1 = get(sp_colmns1) # Method 1
abc.df[,"b_vector_method2"] = get(sp_colmns1) # Method 2
print(abc.df)

sp_colmns2 = c("b_list")
# Similarly : 
# The same code as above, but does not work
# Only difference is b_list is a list
abc.df$b_list_method1 = get(sp_colmns2) # Method 1 (Works)
# TODO: Need to get the reason for & Solve the error on following line
# abc.df[,"b_list_method2"] = get(sp_colmns2) # Method 2 (Doesnt work)
print(abc.df)
```

Comment: Your code snippet does not compile.  AFAIK, the two versions should be semantically identical, and do the same things.

Comment: Why do you want to do it this way so badly?

Comment: Hi Tim,`abc.df[,"b"] = get("b")` gives an error , so you might want to run the snippet without that line. Essentially `abc.df[,"b"] = b` is the same as `abc.df$b = b` if `b` is a vector , but it fails for lists...

Comment: Hi @jay.sf , I have the column names stored separately `sp_colmns`, might also need to iterate over it in future, and also need consistency in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite a lot of trial and error, this seems to work.
The solution turns out to be quite a simple one...

`list(get(sp_colmns2))` instead of `get(sp_colmns2)`

```
abc.df = NULL
a = 1:10
abc.df = data.frame(a)
b_vector = 11:20
b_list = rep(list(c(1,2)),10)

sp_colmns1 = c("b_vector")
# This works :
abc.df$b_vector_method1 = get(sp_colmns1) # Method 1
abc.df[,"b_vector_method2"] = get(sp_colmns1) # Method 2
print(abc.df)

sp_colmns2 = c("b_list")
# Similarly : 
# The same code as above, but does not work
# Only difference is b_list is a list
abc.df$b_list_method1 = get(sp_colmns2) # Method 1 (Works)
# TODO: Need to get the reason for & Solve the error on following line
abc.df[,"b_list_method2"] = list(get(sp_colmns2)) # Method 2 (Doesnt work)
print(abc.df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add the list with any name `"new"` and change the column name in a second step with the string you saved somewhere else.

```
abc.df$new <- get(sp_colmns2)
names(abc.df)[which(names(abc.df) == "new")] <- "b_list_method2"

# > head(abc.df)
#   a b_list_method2
# 1 1           1, 2
# 2 2           1, 2
# 3 3           1, 2
# 4 4           1, 2
# 5 5           1, 2
# 6 6           1, 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.. While this does work, just keeping it as a last option, just in case a cleaner programming approach turns up... Nevertheless does anyone know why it is so ?